# Why is this set closed?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $a \in X$ and $r \ge 0$.

Define: $E_r(a) = \{b \in X : d(a,b) \le r\}$

I want to show that $E_r(a)$ is closed.

Here's what I know: $E_r(a)$ is closed if every limit point $l$ of $E_r(a)$ is in $E_r(a)$. So suppose that $l$ is a limit point of $E_r(a)$. Hence, every neighborhood of $l$ contains a point $m \ne l$ such that $m \in E_r(a)$.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can show that $l \in E_r(a)$ ?

Or do you propose a different strategy?

Comment: I fixed the formatting in the first line of your post. Can you fix the rest?

Comment: Note that $\{foo\}$ is `\{foo\}`.

Comment: I might of "fixed" the second line. I'm sorry I'm not exactly sure what you want. Please let me know if there is something else I should change

Comment: When formatting an equation, the entire equation should lie between the dollar signs. If you want a variable name not to be italicized, use, say, `\mathrm x`. If you want text in your equation, use, say, `\text{and}`. I fixed up this post; look over the source to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy I would suggest is to use the fact that a set is closed if and only if its complement is open.

**Bigger hint:**

> If a point is *not* in the closed ball, then its distance from the center is *greater than* the radius of the ball.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about continuous functions, then $E_r(a)=f^{-1}([0,r])$, where $f(x)=d(a,x)$. Now $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $[0,r]$ is closed. Hence $E_r(a)$ is closed.

The main point of course is that $f$ is continuous. It is actually uniformly continuous because it is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant equal to $1$, due to the triangle inequality.